# Node Js Strapi Backend Deploy on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, strapi

How to deploy Strapi node Js on AWS. Please Guide me.

How should I deploy strapi application on aws.
Confusion In services and costing with database.
How to deploy the strapi code on AWS and how am I going to publish it on AWS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.